# Extract all column values row-wise by a particular row name in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have this matrix M:

```
           V1
B001E4KFG0 A3SGXH7AUHU8GW
B00813GRG4 A1D87F6ZCVE5NK
B00813GRG4 ABXLMWJIXXAIN
```

Now if I want to extract all column values by the rowname "B00813GRG4" what should I do. I tried `M["B00813GRG4",]` but it gives me only "A1D87F6ZCVE5NK" and not both "A1D87F6ZCVE5NK" and "ABXLMWJIXXAIN"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `==` to return a logical vector and then it can be used to subset the rows.

```
M[rownames(M)=='B00813GRG4',, drop=FALSE]
#            V1              
# B00813GRG4 "A1D87F6ZCVE5NK"
# B00813GRG4 "ABXLMWJIXXAIN"
```

using the 'B00813GRG4' as row index will return only the first matching element similar to using `match`.

```
 M[match('B00813GRG4', rownames(M)),, drop=FALSE]
 #           V1              
 #B00813GRG4 "A1D87F6ZCVE5NK"
```